# 'was' vs 'were' an abundance

Tags: grammar

I usually get this right, but for some reason this particular phrase is giving me headaches. The phrase in question is:

"Not that there ***were*** an abundance of sticks or building supplies"

Ordinarily, as the sticks/building supplies are plural I'd assume *were*; however, as I consider 'an abundance' to be a singular object encompassing multiple other objects, it gives me pause. Should it be "*was* an abundance of sticks or building supplies"?

Which is more correct?

Edit: my English teacher uncle just called, quite fortuitously, and advised that I was correct in my original assertion that it should be *was an abundance*. He also reminded me that 'a multitude' follows the same rules (which I knew, and had completely forgotten).

Comment: 'Was an abundance' feels right to me.

Comment: See the definition and usage of *abundance* in a good dictionary. Good Luck.

Comment: You could answer your own question, now that you have the answer. https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I think this could be a American-English / British-English difference.  I've seen & heard British speakers use the plural when the subject is collective noun.  E.g. from a C.S. Lewis book:  "The vicar says that Mrs. Fidget is at rest. Let us hope that she is.  What's certain is that her family are."  And from a Monty Python sketch:  "And the crowd are loving it!  They're really enjoying this novel!"

Comment: @JDM-GBG, I’m British and those examples seem correct to me. I would use "was" in the original question. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Crowd+is%2Ccrowd+are&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CCrowd%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcrowd%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCrowd%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccrowd%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcrowd%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCrowd%20are%3B%2Cc0) puts the singular as more common (AmE or BrE), but the distinction might be more to do with family as individuals or as a group.

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspecting this is a case of the almost non-existent use of the subjunctive mood/tense in English, mostly present when using the verb "to be".  If the use is hypothetical, one almost always uses the subjunctive, as in "if I were you."  In this case it's not quite clear and both, I think, could be used depending on the intent. The use in the example here is more a definite statement of fact than hypothesis and I'd feel more comfortable using "was".

Answer (score -1):

> Not that there **was** an abundance *of sticks or building supplies*.

The above sentence is correct because *of sticks or building supplies* is just some additional information about the abundance you meant, i.e., it answers **Abundance of what?**.

If only there was **and** instead of **or** in your sentence both **were** and **was** would be correct conveying different meaning.

1. Not that there **were** *an abundance of sticks* and *building supplies*.
2. Not that there **was** an abundance *of sticks and building supplies*.